# Ajax request to rails server using jQuery with phonegap not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to send a login request to rails Restful API from my Phonegap app on iOS.
Following code works with jQuery 1.5 but not with jQuery 1.4.2.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

`$.ajax({

    type: 'POST', 
    url: urlFactory.getLoginURL(),

    data: { 'email': emailVal, 'password': passwordVal },

    success: onSuccess,

    error: onError,
    dataType: "json"

});`

The web server gives me the following error:

`Started POST "/login.json" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Apr 18 00:29:38 +0100 2011

  Processing by SessionsController#create as JSON

  Parameters: {"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"example@gmail.com"}

  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE (users.id IS NULL) LIMIT 1

Completed   in 251ms

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):

  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:37:in require_authorisation_happened'

Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-  3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.4ms)

Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-  3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (14.1ms)

Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-  3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (23.4ms)`

It returns following in the successful case:

`Started POST "/login.json" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Apr 18 00:16:25 +0100 2011

  Processing by SessionsController#create as JSON

  Parameters: {"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"example@gmail.com"}

  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT`users`.* FROM`users`WHERE (`users`.`id`IS NULL) LIMIT 1

  User Load (19.4ms)  SELECT`users`.* FROM`users`WHERE (`users`.`email= 'example@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 306ms (Views: 4.6ms | ActiveRecord: 19.7ms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an authenticity token. In rails2 you can use form_authenticity_token in your view to render the authenticity token and then you'll need to add that to the parameters submitted by the form.

In Rails3 it's easier. Just add <%= csrf_meta_tag %> in the head of your layout and then ensure you use the rails.js library for the ajax. This will pickup the authenticity token and submit it with the form.

There is a short writeup here http://www.themodestrubyist.com/2010/02/24/rails-3-ujs-and-csrf-meta-tags/

And an example app here https://github.com/grigio/rails3-ujs-demo.git

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As long as I understand, rails.js is used for file uploads. Indeed, it does something only when it detects file type in the submitted form. In addition, csrf token is turned off with json request in default with rails3. Also, I think it doesn't explain why it works with jquery 1.5 but 1.4.2.

Comment: Rails.js enables unobtrusive javascript scripting (UJS) and interprets Rails data attributes, picks up the csrf_meta_tag and works with the Rails helpers that implement :remote => true. But rails.js doesn't work with jQuery 1.4.2 only 1.4.3 or later.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your answer I think I know the problem now. I thought rails turn off the protect_from_forgery option for json but it seems it does not. The reason why it worked with jquery 1.5 was because rails version before 3.04 had a problem that protect_from_forgery does not work under specific conditions.